# Set if conditions based on radio input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to setup 3 radio inputs like below , click a button and trigger the function to run for which if statement corresponds with the radio value. I'm sure this is easy , but i'm pulling my hair out as a noob.

```
<input type="radio" id="load_Template" name="settings" value="load_Template">
<label for="load_Template">Load Template</label><br>

<input type="radio" id="load_settings" name="settings" value="load_settings">
<label for="load_settings">Load Settings</label><br>

<input type="radio" id="reset_MFL" name="settings" value="reset_MFL">
<label for="reset_MFL">Reset MFL</label>
```

Then have a button when clicked will run the function for which radio is clicked

```
<input id="LoadSettings" type="button" onclick="LoadSettings()" value="Load Settings">
```

Here is script to execute that would correspond with what radio input was checked

```
// IF RADIO INPUT FOR "LOAD_TEMPLATE" CHECKED THEN RUN THIS ONCLICK LOADSETTINGS
if (load_Template) {
 function AdjustSettings() {
  alert('load_Template');
 }
}

// IF RADIO INPUT FOR "LOAD_SETTINGS" CHECKED THEN RUN THIS ONCLICK LOADSETTINGS
if (load_settings) {
 function AdjustSettings() {
  alert('load_settings');
 }
}

// IF RADIO INPUT FOR "RESET_MFL" CHECKED THEN RUN THIS ONCLICK LOADSETTINGS
if (reset_MFL) {
 function AdjustSettings() {
  alert('reset_MFL');
 }
}

// CLICK THIS BUTTON TO TRIGGER WHICH IF STATEMENT MATCHES RADIO VALUE
function LoadSettings() {
  AdjustSettings();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logical issue with the way you have written your script. The conditionals need to be embedded inside the scope of a function to be executed not the other way around. Here's an implementation using jquery and switch cases:

```js
function AdjustSettings(){
  switch ($('input[name="settings"]:checked').val()){
    case "load_Template":
      alert("load_template");
      break;
    case "load_settings":
      alert("load_settings");
      break;
    case "reset_MFL":
      alert("reset_MFL");
      break;

  }

}

// CLICK THIS BUTTON TO TRIGGER WHICH IF STATEMENT MATCHES RADIO VALUE
function LoadSettings() {
  AdjustSettings();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <input type="radio" id="load_Template" name="settings" value="load_Template">
    <label for="load_Template">Load Template</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="load_settings" name="settings" value="load_settings">
    <label for="load_settings">Load Settings</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="reset_MFL" name="settings" value="reset_MFL">
    <label for="reset_MFL">Reset MFL</label>
    <input id="LoadSettings" type="button" onclick="LoadSettings()" value="Load Settings">



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Advise: use `.addEventListener()` instead of inline `onclick`...

Then, on click of the button, look for the checked radio button. Do nothing if none. If there is one, get its value and compare it to decide what to do.

That makes it one single function.

```js
document.querySelector("#LoadSettings").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  let checkedRadio = document.querySelector("[name='settings']:checked")
  if (!checkedRadio) return;

  let value = checkedRadio.value

  if (value === "load_Template") {
    alert('load_Template');
  }

  if (value === "load_settings") {
    alert('load_settings');
  }

  if (value === "reset_MFL") {
    alert('reset_MFL');
  }

})
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="load_Template" name="settings" value="load_Template">
<label for="load_Template">Load Template</label><br>

<input type="radio" id="load_settings" name="settings" value="load_settings">
<label for="load_settings">Load Settings</label><br>

<input type="radio" id="reset_MFL" name="settings" value="reset_MFL">
<label for="reset_MFL">Reset MFL</label>

<br>
<input id="LoadSettings" type="button" value="Load Settings">
```